# Where should I call Free() function?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should I call Free() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544383/where-should-i-call-free-function)

When I used 
"valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./Main"
to check the memory leak, I had some errors because of not using Free(), but I don't know where can I use Free() in this method? I need to allocate the memory for new data, if I call free? It means I will delete the data I have put in ??? This is a bit silly:(

---

In header file

```
typedef struct TreeNode * Node;
```

In this .c file:

```
struct TreeNode {
char* theData;
Node Left;
Node Right;};
```

This is a recursive function !

```
Node InsertString(Node tree, char* data) {

if (tree == NULL) {
    tree = malloc(sizeof (struct TreeNode));//Error
    if (tree == NULL) {
        printf("Out of Space!\n");
    } else {
        tree->theData = malloc(sizeof (char) * strlen(data));//Error
        strcpy(tree->theData, data);
        tree->Left = tree->Right = NULL;


    }
} else {
        if (strcmp(data, tree->theData) < 0) {
            tree->Left = InsertString(head, tree->Left, data);//Error
        } else {
            if (strcmp(data, tree->theData) > 0) {
                tree->Right = InsertString(head, tree->Right, data);//Error
            } else {
                printf("This String already Existed\n");
            }
        }
    } 

}
return tree;}
```

---

And this is how I call this function in another .c file

```
currentTree = InsearchString(currentTree,"String");
```

Thank you for reading my post. Happy new Year :P

Comment: You just posted this question. Why start a new question if it's not resolved?

Comment: @Tuan, @user552279: is this just that you are the same person, or are both of you posting the same homework? Really suspicious that someone writes code as this one, uses valgrind, and then isn't able to interpret the results by himself. The exercise is a good one. You'll only learn if you think about it yourself.

Comment: I wrote those 2 questions, but plz read them carefully, they are different.In the first one, I didn't explain everything carefully, and i could not find where to edit, thus i post this again with the same title but the contents are not all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact problem is because of how you declared your function, specifically with the first parameter. The way you pass `Node` makes the `TreeNode` instance being passed as an `in/out` parameter; but the pointer itself is passed by value to the function and is considered an `in` parameter. Thus, when you attempt to modify the value of the pointer, by calling `malloc`, the modified value will not be passed back to the function caller. And since the function caller does not have access to the newly allocated memory, it won't be able to `free` it, and the memory block will be leaked.

Valgrind detects this and warns you properly; however, since it doesn't know the semantic of your code, it can only tell you that you need to delete the memory block allocated in the function.

The right fix, based on the intended semantic would be to pass `Node *` or `Node &` to the function, which would allow you to manipulate the original value of the pointer, instead of the call stack copy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a recursive deallocating function, but of course you would only do it when you really want to free up the memory. You can also delete, individual TreeNode, but implementation of that will be little bit more complicated.

Here is how you should free up the used memory when the tree is no longer required.

```
void FreeUpTree(Node root)
{
if ( root == NULL ) return;
FreeUpTree(root-Left);
FreeUpTree(root-Right);
free(root->data);
free(root);
}
```