# Free where to use it

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should I call Free() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544383/where-should-i-call-free-function)

I have this init method to init a queue and I use a malloc. My question is if malloc is well used and if I have to use a free because I have a malloc, and where?

```
    void e1_init(e1queue_t* q){
     q->head = 0;
     q->tail = sizeof(q->queue)/sizeof(int)-1;
     q=(e1queue_t*) malloc( sizeof(e1queue_t));
     q->size=0;  
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: When you're done with the queue, you'll need to call a e1_deinit or similar function on it.

Comment: You should change the function to "e1queue_t *e1_init(void)". Then free() is applied to what the function returns when you are done using it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that code does what you think it does.  Once that function returns, you've lost the pointer to the allocated memory.  `q` is only modified in the scope of the function.  (The entire function is a bit nonsensical to be honest.  The use of it would be *very* odd.)

Anyway, to answer your question, you would have a matching `e1_destroy` or `e1_free` method that's responsible for properly cleaning up  the contents of the struct.

Comment: In that method all I do is init the head that is a int with the first position in the queue, tail that is the last position of the queue and size that has the size of the queue. I searched and I think that a malloc is needed (and when a malloc is used I have to use a free too) when I init the queue, am I right?  Thanks

Comment: Corbin is right, tomss. To help you, we need the code of the e1queue_t struct. Please post it.